# Regex para aspas simples

Tags: php, regex

Gostaria de remover as aspas simples no meio de um texto, ignorando as do inicio e fim, se caso existir.

- 1º Caso: `'Texto e pala'vras'` = `'Texto e palavras'`
- 2º Caso: `Texto e pala'vras` = `Texto e palavras`

Comment: Realmente precisa de uma regex? `str_replace()` não resolve o problema?

Comment: não posso substituir todas, tenho que preservar as aspas simples do inicio e do fim.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode usar a regex `(?<!^)'(?!$)`.

A sintaxe `(?<!` determina um [*lookbehind negativo*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind), ou seja, ele verifica se algo não existe antes da posição atual. Dentro deste *lookbehind* temos o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`, que significa "início da string".

Em seguida temos o próprio caractere `'`.

Logo depois temos `(?!`, que determina um [*lookahead negativo*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead). De forma similar ao *lookbehind*, ele verifica se algo não existe depois da posição atual. Dentro dele temos o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`, que significa "final da string".

Ou seja, a regex pega todos os caracteres `'` (aspas simples), desde que não estejam no início ou no final da string. Assim, podemos usar esta regex na função [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (lembrando de escapar o caractere `'` com `\`):

```
$texto = '\'Texto e pala\'vras\'';
$texto = preg_replace('/(?<!^)\'(?!$)/', '', $texto);
echo $texto;
```

O `preg_replace` substitui todas estas aspas por uma string vazia (ou seja, na prática estas aspas são removidas da string). O resultado é `'Texto e palavras'`.

Comment: Era tudo que eu precisava.
Não sabia que dava para usar o lookahead dessa forma.
Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Pode resolver esse problema alternativamente com `str_replace()` e `substr()`. Primeiro são removidas todas as aspas simples, depois é feita uma checagem com `substr()` se o primeiro e o último caracteres são aspas simples e no final `printf/sprintf()` monta o template final.

```
function removerAspas($str){
    $str = trim($str);
    $aspaInicio  = substr($str, 0, 1) == "'" ? "'" : '';
    $aspaFim = substr($str, -1, 1)  == "'" ? "'" : '';
    $strLimpa = str_replace("'", '', $str);

    return sprintf("%s%s%s", $aspaInicio, $strLimpa, $aspaFim);
}

echo removerAspas("'Texto e pala'vras'") .PHP_EOL;
echo removerAspas("Texto e pala'vras#'") .PHP_EOL;
echo removerAspas("'#Texto e pala'vras") .PHP_EOL;
echo removerAspas("Te'x'to' 'e' pala'vras") .PHP_EOL;
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/wlehZJ)